# How to provide default implementation of protocol's methods for generic class and its subclasses?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols

I am currently learning Swift's generics and encountered a problem with using protocol alongside generic classes. I need to create 4 wrapper classes which inherit from `AWMediaItemWrapper` generic class.

```
public class MPMediaItemWrapper<M: MPMediaEntity> {
    internal let value: M
    init(_ value: M) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

`MPMediaEntity` is an abstract class coming from `MediaPlayer` framework. The three subclasses that inherit from it are the same:

```
public class MPTrack: MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaItem> {}
public class MPAlbum: MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaItem> {}
public class MPArtist: MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaItem> {}
```

Except for the forth one:

```
public class MPPlaylist: MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaPlaylist> {}
```

I also have a protocol `AWMediaItem` that defines some properties and methods

```
public protocol AWMediaItem: class {
    /// Unique identifier of the item.
    var uid: String { get }
    
    /// Name used to identify the item, for example album title or artist name.
    var name: String { get }

    /// Source of the object.
    var source: AWMediaSource { get }

    ...
}
```

Now what I'd like to do is create a default `AWMediaItem` implementation for the `MPMediaItemWrapper` subclasses in which the `M` class is `MPMediaEntity` (both `MPMediaItem` and `MPMediaPlaylist` are subclasses of it)

I have written this code

```
public extension AWMediaItem where Self: MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaEntity> {
    var source: AWMediaSource {
        return .iTunes
    }
    
    var uid: String {
        return String(value.persistentID)
    }
}
```

It doesn't give me errors but the compiler says that all of the three subclasses are missing protocol requirements.

> Type 'MPArtist' does not conform to protocol 'AWMediaItem'

> Type 'MPAlbum' does not conform to protocol 'AWMediaItem'

> Type 'MPTrack' does not conform to protocol 'AWMediaItem'

> Type 'MPPlaylist' does not conform to protocol 'AWMediaItem'

If I change the protocol extension to

```
public extension AWMediaItem where Self: MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaItem>
```

the protocol requirements are fulfilled for `MPTrack`, `MPAlbum` and `MPArtist` but not for `MPPlaylist`. Is there any way to write the extension so it works for all of those subclasses?

Comment: Copy-pasted.... no compiler error. Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Didn't you forget anything?

Comment: you'll need to actually try conforming the 4 child classes to the protocol to see the compiler errors.

Comment: That’s correct, @flanker

Answer (score 2):

I think the root of your problem is you are assuming inheritance from the specific type used to instantiate the generic and that is not the case.

`MPTrack.self is MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaEntity>.Type` will always fail

`MPTrack.self is MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaItem>.Type` will always be true

despite `MPMediaItem` being a subclass of `NPMedidiaEntity`, `MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaItem>` is not a subclass of `MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaEntity>`.  Put simply, the two are completely different classes, more siblings than parent: child.

Therefore you are not getting the behaviour you are expecting in the protocol from the default implementation, as

`public extension AWMediaItem where Self: MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaEntity>`

will not apply for any of your classes as none of them conform to the where clause.  Therefore they do not get the default implementation and give the conformance errors.

However three of the classes are created as subclasses of `MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaItem>`, so when you change the protocol extension to

`public extension AWMediaItem where Self: MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaItem>`

they now do conform, obtain the default implementation, and don't error.  Your playlist class however still doesn't conform as it inherits from `MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaPlaylist>`

The easy solution would be to have two extensions, both with the same default implementation, one for

`public extension AWMediaItem where Self: MPMediaItemWrapper<MPMediaItem>`

and one for

`public extension AWMediaItem where Self: MPMediaItemWrapper< MPMediaPlaylist>`

When I work out the better way to do this, and I'm sure there is one, I'll update the answer!

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in such clear terms! I was thinking about the inheritance in a wrong way